# Angular - creating a web component and using in the project

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, web-component

How can I change one module to a web component and use it in the project? For example I have 3 modules in the project below and I want to change only module1 to web component and use in the same project?

Thanks

Source code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8xwotj

Answer (score 0):

In angular currently you can not create a web component of one separate module.

But here is a work around;-

1) create a duplicate project.

2) remove all the modules from the project except the one that you wanna use as web component.

3) convert duplicate project into the library [like this](https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries)

4) Lastly, Use that created library in your original project.

I hope this will help you. Let me know the results